# How much would/did it cost to create Robocop?

Tags: robots, costume, robocop-1987, robocop

How much money (USD-$) did it cost (or theoretically would have costed) Omni Consumer Products to build and create Robocop?

Comment: Do you want that fictional amount in Quatloo or Triganic Pu?

Comment: Intriguing question. My first guess is less than the *"[50 million dollars in interest payments alone](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/RoboCop)"*.

Comment: @Wikis - I was just thinking that. My maths isn't good enough to work out the cost of the principle if the interest is $50m in 6 mos but it must be less than that.

Comment: Out of universe, it cost over $1M for the suit; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCop

Comment: How much is a human life worth? Are you only considering actual build, or the R&D involved as well?

Comment: @phantom42 - I think the human component was free. *"[He signed the release forms when he joined the force, he's legally dead... we can do pretty much what we want to him](http://robocop.wikia.com/wiki/RoboCop_(cyborg_1987))"*

Comment: The original or the reboot version?

Comment: @Chris: original, see tag (1987).

Comment: @Richard You can't solve for the principal without also knowing the internet rate.

Comment: @jackbnimble - Very true, but you can set an absolute lower and likely upper bound. They can't have borrowed at less than zero and large corporations rarely borrow money at more than a few percent.

Answer (score 3):

### ** Warning - Lots and lots of unfounded assumptions below - Warning. **

We know that the cost of turning Alex Murphy into Robocop in the 2014 [reboot](http://scriptdrive.net/attachment.php?aid=999) was $2Bn. This evidently included a customised overseas facility and a dedicated (and extensive) R&D programme.

> **NORTON (CONT'D):** *Let me phrase this so there's no misunderstanding. A two billion dollar, psychotic killing machine is
>   loose out there - and we're most likely its top two targets. Is that
>   clear enough for you?*

By comparison, the Robocop trial programme in the 1987 version is *all kinds of cheap*, built in a basement facility in downtown Detroit, a junior OCP exec's  pet project running with just a handful of staff.

If we assume that they spent 90% less in the original film, and then taking into account the [currency shift](http://www.calculatorweb.com/calculators/inflationcalc.shtml) between 1987 and 2014, that gives us a very *very* rough figure of around **$80-100M** to turn Alex Murphy into Robocop in the 1987 film.

Comment: Why would OCP be using pounds? I agree with the overall cheapness of the operation, but is there evidence that they cannibalized spare parts? The arm, which is the only bit of RoboCop we see before the finished product, certainly belies that assumption. The impression I got was that they had the basic tech to keep however much brain they harvested from Murphy alive and interface to it, but they were still working on the prostheses, which took several months to develop.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - Oops. I forgot to switch the currency marker over :-)

Comment: @JohnSensebe - That's a fair point. In the 1987 film the Robocop programme is a pet project of a junior VP but there's no indication that they aren't researching new tech. That being said, compare it to what we see in the reboot...

Comment: I don't think you can compare it to the reboot, though. They are completely different films. Again, I agree with you that the 1987 RoboCop was built on the cheap with limited resources, but it's outright stated in the film (though it could be exaggeration) that the project is "ready to go", implying that the project has been underway alongside the ED-209 project for some time. And there is no indication in the movie (or indeed the entire pre-reboot franchise) that the tech needed to interface a computer to a bit of brain tissue existed anywhere else.

Comment: But can I buy that for a dollar?